# Can not use cvsnakeimage in opencv 2.4

Tags: opencv

I need to use the cvsnakeimage function for active contours but apparently it is not available in opencv2.4.

I have opencv2.4 installed on my PC. I have already linked my VS2010 project to opencv_legacy242d.lib but still cvSnakeImage is undefined.

Comment: Do you include the legacy header?

Answer (score 4):

Don't forget to:

```
#include <opencv2/legacy/legacy.hpp>
```

and make sure you are linking with either `opencv_legacy242.lib` or `opencv_legacy242d.lib`.

I don't have a Windows box at my disposal, but this worked  on Mac OS X.